# Zeros of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic on the $D_r(z_0)$ and let $z_0\in D_r(z_0)$. If $f(z_0)=0$ either it is identically zero in the disk or non zero on some punctured sub-disk centered at $z_0$.

This is where I am a bit confused. Say $z_n\in D_r(z_0)$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_nz_n=z_0$. I saw in a text book that $f=0$ in some disk due to continuity. Why can't it be non-zero in a disk as I mentioned in the previous paragraph? Small confusion any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Thanks for the edit

Comment: The statement could be worded like this: "If $f$ is analytic and not constant, then at any point $z_0$, there is a small disc $D$ containing $z_0$ such that for every $z \in D$, $f(z)=f(z_0)$ implies $z=z_0$." So the punctured disc with no zeros might be much smaller than your $D_r(z_0)$. Does that help?

Comment: The wording remains confusing and unclear.  In short, the zeros of an analytic function are isolated.  I cannot tell if you do not understand how this fact implies something else, or how one proves this fact in the first place.

Comment: My guess is that the result you saw in the text book said that if $z_n \to z_0$, and $f(z_n) = 0$, and $z_n \ne z_0$, then $f$ is identically zero.  This doesn't contradict your first paragraph.